# Find tax percent given tax amount and total amount

Tags: arithmetic

First, I will start with example ...

for example meal price is : 105

and meal total price + the tip is : 120

so left with : 15

how I can tell how much % the 15 is from the 105 (meal price)?

Comment: $\frac {15}{105}\cdot 100\approx 14.285 %$

Comment: hello sir , so i do 15 / 105 * 100 ?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is generally done to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: thank you very much . so the result is 14.285% right?

Comment: To be precise, it is $\frac 17$ which equals $14.286 %$ when rounded to $3$ d.p.

Comment: gotca thank you , sorry for the silly questions xD

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you. :)

Comment: Raptor, please do not answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The "percent" one number is of another is the equivalent number of parts per one hundred.

So, for example, since $\dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{\boxed{25}}{100}$, you know $1$ is $25\%$ of $4$. To compute that, you would be solving $\dfrac 14 = \dfrac p{100}$ for $p$.

In your specific case, you want to solve $$\frac{15}{105}=\frac{p}{100}$$
You then obtain
$$p = \frac{100\cdot 15}{105}\approx 14.3,$$
that is, $15$ is approximately $14.3\%$ of $105$.